# Is a gRPC API returning "Any" a good idea?

Tags: grpc

I understand that there is no right or wrong answer here.

I see a gRPC API which returns "google.protobuf.Any". The job of the API is to take a param, which says what information needs to be fetched, and returns one of "n" things.

From an API design perspective, it is a good practice to define an API like this?
The other option would be to define a return message with "oneof" construct, which in my opinion tightly binds what the API can return.

Please let me know your thoughts.

Thanks for your time.

```
rpc getInformation(InfomationRequestParams) returns (google.protobuf.Any);
```

Answer (score 0):

Returning Any from an API is common. `oneof` is preferred if you have a strict set of options that aren't added to often, but isn't appropriate if *anyone* may want to extend what is sent. The decision is similar to whether you choose to use an `enum` or a `string` in an API.

It does seem weird to not wrap the Any with a message, since generally there is type-independent information. But that's more specific to what your API actually provides and so may be fine as-is.